# Webpage layout is breaking up

Tags: html, css

been working and learning to build this page for about 4-5 hours and I cannot seem to find out why I am unable to get the navigation links on the same line as the navbar-logo and secondly is there any way I could make this code more efficient and less dependent/error-prone?

One more thing I wanted to ask is can we use flexbox in this webpage? and is CSS animation used is efficient here?

```css
body{
    background-color: #000;
   color: #f1f1f1;
   animation: fade-in 2s 1;

}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: auto;
}


.navbar-logo{
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 100px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 100;
}
.navbar-logo-sub{
    padding: 55px 0px 0px 200px;
}

#logo-main{
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
   color: white;
   font-size: 40px;
   font-weight: 800;
   margin: 0;
}
.parenthesis1{
    color: #b22121;
   font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
}
.parenthesis2{
    color: #787878;
   font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
}
#logo-sub{
    color: white;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 20;
   font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;

}
#banner-image{
    width: 50%;
   padding-left: 20%;
   filter: blur(3px);
   position: relative;
   padding-top: 5%;
}
#banner-text{
   top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: left;
}
nav{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 60%;
}
li{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 100px;
   list-style-type: none;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
}

h1{
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: -50px;
   font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
   font-weight: 300;
   text-shadow: 4px 2px rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
   opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 3s 1 forwards;

}
div h1:nth-of-type(2){
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(3){
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(4){
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(5){
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(6){
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(7){
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
   
div h1:nth-of-type(8){
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
   
div h1:nth-of-type(9){
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
   
@keyframes slide-in {
    0%{
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100%{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1.0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
    0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateY(25%);
    opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    0%{
    opacity: 0.0;
    }
    50%{
   opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100%{
    opacity: 1.0;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
 <title>.whatsthecode.</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Didact+Gothic|Coming+Soon|Bungee|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
 <header>
 <div class="navbar-logo">
 <p id="logo-main">WhatsTheCode<span class="parenthesis1">(</span>
    <span class="parenthesis2">)</span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-logo-sub"><p id="logo-sub">{&lt;html&gt;<span style="color: #b22121">&lt;style&gt;</span><span style="color: #787878">&lt;script&gt;</span>}</p></div>
     <nav>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.html">FAQ</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
 </ul>
    </nav>
 </header>
 <section>
 <div class="banner">
 <img src="banner-background.png" id="banner-image">
 <div id="banner-text"><h1>Your</h1><h1>web development</h1>
    <h1>develops</h1><h1>here.</h1></div>
 </div>
 </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go brother, I added a **div with class="navbar-wrapper"** and placed the header elements inside it. I used the **display:inline-block on the header elements** so that they are horizontally aligned. For the **navbar-logo-sub, I placed it inside the navbar-logo and used position:absolute, and bottom:0** to place it at the bottom of the parent element. Run Code snippet and view it on full page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  animation: fade-in 2s 1;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-wrapper{
 padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px;
}

header .navbar-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

header nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

header .navbar-logo-sub {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20%;
}

nav {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header li:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#logo-main {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
}

.parenthesis1 {
  color: #b22121;
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
}

.parenthesis2 {
  color: #787878;
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
}

#logo-sub {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 20;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
}

#banner-image {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  filter: blur(3px);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

#banner-text {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 3s 1 forwards;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(7) {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(8) {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

div h1:nth-of-type(9) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateY(25%);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>.whatsthecode.</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Didact+Gothic|Coming+Soon|Bungee|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="navbar-logo">
        <p id="logo-main">WhatsTheCode<span class="parenthesis1">(</span>
          <span class="parenthesis2">)</span></p>
        <div class="navbar-logo-sub">
          <p id="logo-sub">{&lt;html&gt;<span style="color: #b22121">&lt;style&gt;</span><span style="color: 
    #787878">&lt;script&gt;</span>}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="banner-background.png" id="banner-image">
      <div id="banner-text">
        <h1>Your</h1>
        <h1>web development</h1>
        <h1>develops</h1>
        <h1>here.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```